# Udev hwdb to re-map a key when I don't know the key code

Tags: keyboard, udev

I've written a file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb` to re-map some of my keyboard keys. There's an additional key that I want to re-map, but I can't figure out what identifier I should use for it.

Ordinarily, I run `evtest` and press keyboard keys to get an output like the following:

```
Event: time 1639158329.532434, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7000f
Event: time 1639158329.532434, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 38 (KEY_L), value 1
```

Then I use the hex "value" from the first line above (containing "EV_MSC") to compose a line like the following in my `70-keyboard.hwdb` file:

```
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7000f=rightctrl
```

The key that I want to re-map now is my `KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN` key, and when I run `evtest` to identify its hex value, I only get one line of output, and it's not the line that contains "EV_MSC":

```
Event: time 1639158417.741165, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 229 (KEY_KBDILLUMDOWN), value 1
```

How can I remap this key in udev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this key event is injected by ACPI driver (instead of real key press event) in which case you may handle it by acpid. Try acpi_listen (while acpid is running). Events handlers are at /etc/acpi/events/ which are calling handlers (default is right in /etc/acpi/).

If that is the case you can write a simple evdev wrapper script to generate keypress events as handler to acpi events. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575528/simulating-key-press-event-using-python-for-linux) for examples.